# Set position on label

Tags: python, pyqt5, position

can you help me please with set of possiotion? I have a problem, because the labels don't move :(

Detail in screen.

label_result.move (X, Y) doesnť work.

```
from datetime import datetime as datetime, timedelta as timedelta
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
# Hlavní okno
main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
main.setWindowTitle('Set tag')
main.setGeometry(60, 60, 300, 600)
# Layout 1
layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
main.setLayout(layout)
# Nápis
label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Číslo sezení')
layout.addWidget(label)
#Input
input_session = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
input_session.move(0,0)
layout.addWidget(input_session)
# Tlačítko
button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Zaznamenat tag')
layout.addWidget(button)
#Sesion Result
label_result = QtWidgets.QLabel('Výsledky \n')
label_result.move (20, 20)
layout.addWidget(label_result)
button.clicked.connect(lambda: test(input_session.text()))
# Spuštění
main.show()
app.exec()
```

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: They are called "layout managers", because the management of layout is *their* responsibility: *they* decide the position (and size) of widgets, not you. So, since 99% of times, using fixed geometries instead of layouts is *not* a good idea, is the right screenshot what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, right is the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Using layout managers means that *all* positioning and sizing of widgets is left to it, so any attempt to manually set the geometry of widget is ignored everytime the widget on which the layout is set is resized, which is what happens at least once as soon as the widget is mapped (shown) the first time.

If you want to position widgets in a *different* layouts, then you need to understand how layout(s) could be structured in order to achieve the desired result. In your case, it could be done in at least 3 slightly different ways:

- using a main *vertical* boxed layout, then adding a horizontal layout for the first three widgets, another one for the last label, and finally a *stretch* (which is an empty layout item that tries to expand itself up to the maximum available extent);
- again a main vertical layout, then a grid layout and again a stretch;
- a grid layout with an expanding spacer at the bottom;

I'll show a possible implementation of the first, leaving the others up to you. Note that I will use a subclass of QWidget, which gives a better code/object structure and allows better implementation.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Set tag')

        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        topLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(topLayout)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Číslo sezení')
        topLayout.addWidget(label)
        input_session = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        topLayout.addWidget(input_session)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Zaznamenat tag')
        topLayout.addWidget(button)

        midLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(midLayout)
        label_result = QtWidgets.QLabel('Výsledky')
        midLayout.addWidget(label_result)

        mainLayout.addStretch()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWidget = MyWidget()
    myWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```